# Extensión de objetos nativos

Tags: javascript, poo

Si tengo un Objeto nativo por ejemplo en Javascript `String`

Y quiero extenderlo.

```
String.change = String.change || function(n) {
 return n.split("");
};
```

Defino un método, pero el interprete en Javascript no sabe si será un método o una variable. Luego verifico si no existe haciendo `String.change || function() {};` con el operador `OR`.

Es así en todos los lenguajes de programación orientada a objetos ?

Me refiero a que tengo la inquietud en que javascript se ejecuta en un interprete, pero otros lenguajes son compilados, y entonces al YO definir

```
String.change
```

y luego verificar si ya existia, esto no tendría ninguna utilidad, ya que yo la he declarado antes de verificar si existia, entonces cómo funciona en Javascript ?

Cómo funciona el tiempo de ejecución en javascript, que aunque YO extendiendo el objeto nativo y DESPUÉS verificando si existe, funcione ? , no debería siempre el `OR` devolver el primer resultado y **NO** crear la función, ya que yo previamente he creado el método.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Cómo funciona el tiempo de ejecución en javascript, que aunque YO extendiendo el objeto nativo y DESPUÉS verificando si existe, funcione ? , no debería siempre el OR devolver el primer resultado y NO crear la función, ya que yo previamente he creado el método.

En `Javascript` tenemos que:

- Se puede definir y crear instancias de objetos en cualquier momento.
- Se puede definir un método o propiedad para un objeto dinámicamente.
- Si el método o propiedad no existe, el valor del mismo es igual a `undefined`

  ```
  console.log(String.change); // Resultado: undefined
  ```
- `undefined` es un valor [`falsy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Glossary/Falsy), y siguiendo la lógica para el `OR`, tenemos:

  ```
  // false || loQueSea => loQueSea
  String.change = String.change || function(){}
  console.log(String.change); // Resultado f(){}
  ```

En resumen, se crea y asigna la función debido `String.change` no estaba definido.

#### Referencia:

[MDN - Introducción a JavaScript orientado a objetos](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introducci%C3%B3n_a_JavaScript_orientado_a_objetos)

---

### Update

En `Javascript` para definir una propiedad o método es necesario asignarle un valor.

#### Demo:

```js
// Vemos el valor
console.log(String.change);
// Verificamos si existe la propiedad
console.log('change' in String);
// Asignamos un valor
String.change = String.change;
// Verificamos si existe la propiedad
console.log('change' in String);
// Vemos el valor
console.log(String.change);
```

Comment: A lo que va enfocada mi pregunta, es verificas si String.change est definido, pero DESPUES de tú mismo definirlo, entonces deberia dar como resultado que SÍ está definido y por ende NO crear la función

Comment: @EduardoSebastian, en `JS` las propiedades/metodos no se "*crean/definen*" por el solo hecho de enunciarlas y es por esto, que al hacer `console.log(String.change)` devuelve `undefined`. Para "crearla/definirla" es necesario asignarle un valor.

Comment: @EduardoSebastian, he actualizado mi respuesta.